# ASP.NET CORE Accessing Image from wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have a website running on Azure.
In one of the pages i'm uploading an image and need to be able to access it via url.
Here is my code for uploading an image:

```
    string webRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    if (files.Count > 0)
    {
        string fileName = "Image1";
        var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, @"Images\AdvertiseImg");
        var extention = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
        using (var filesStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, 
       fileName+extention), FileMode.Create))
        {
            files[0].CopyTo(filesStreams);
        }
```

It looks like the URL is not getting the correct photo, because when i'm replacing the photo with another one i'm still getting the same old photo.
I even tried to delete all images from the folder in Azure using Kudu(see attached image)
but i'm still getting the old photo
[image]

The url i'm trying to get the photo from is :

> https://domainName.azurewebsites.net/Images/AdvertiseImg/Image1.jpeg

looks like i'm using the wrong url but i cant understand which one is it.
any thoughts?

> 

Comment: sounds like standard browser chaching.  Try ctrl-F5 in browser.  You can add a "refresh" paramater to the URL to avoid this.  So something like: ...domainName.azurewebsites.net/Images/AdvertiseImg/Image1.jpeg?12098109  (The number would be current milliseconds after file upload/update is complete.)  The browser will ignore the "?xxxx" part but because it's not the same SRC, force a load.

Comment: If you always create a new record on update, this could also be the record's UID... (or use the UID in the filename itself...)

Comment: Thank you, adding "?xxx" is exactly what was missing

Answer (score 0):

> looks like I'm using the wrong URL but I can't understand which one is
> it. any thoughts?

Please check the image is properly uploaded to a www-root folder. In your case show `0 Files(2) 0 bytes`

Use the following steps to access wwwroot folder files.

1. Go to the application and select Advanced Tools from the left-hand menu.
2. Click on Go link.
3. On the top menu under Debug console and select CMD.
   [image]
4. You can try using wwwroot. like mydomain\images\image.PNG

[image]

5. In your case show 0 files. Please check image upload is properly on the wwwroot folder or not.